# React seems to re-render the wrong component when triggering another one

Tags: reactjs

I have two components in my project.

One is Aapp.jsx

One is Child.jsx

When I called the state set function in Child 1; it is supposed to see mentioning child 1 in the console, but now it is showing child 3. It is weird and why is that?

[image]

I guess the reason is "key" in prop, so I added "key" there too. But the problem is still there.

Here is the code:
App:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {Child} from './Child.jsx'
export function App(props) {

  [message,setMessage]=useState('');
  [showChild1,setShowChild1]=useState(true);
  [showChild2,setShowChild2]=useState(true);
  [showChild3,setShowChild3]=useState(true);

[child1data,setChild1data] = useState('child1');
[child2data,setChild2data] = useState('child2');
[child3data,setChild3data] = useState('child3');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('parent was rendered')
  })
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      

<button onClick={()=>setShowChild1(!showChild1)}>Show child1</button>
{showChild1 && <Child key='1' data={child1data}/>}
<br/>
<br/>
<button onClick={()=>setShowChild2(!showChild2)}>Show child2</button>
{showChild2 && <Child key='2'data={child2data}/>}

<br/>
<br/>
<button onClick={()=>setShowChild3(!showChild3)}>Show child3</button>
<br/>
{showChild3 && <Child key='3' data={child3data}/>}
      

    </div>
  );
}

// Log to console
console.log('Hello console')
```

Child:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export const Child = (props) => {

const {data} = props;

[message,setMessage]=useState('');

useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(data)
  console.log(message)
})

  return <>
  
  <h1>This is {data}</h1>
  <input onChange={((e)=>setMessage(e.target.value))}></input>
  
  </>
}
```

For better illustrate, here is my code
https://playcode.io/940717

Comment: Can you make this into a runnable [mcve] (either here or on something like Code Sandbox) so we can observe as well?

Comment: https://playcode.io/940717

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky one but fortunately comes with a very simple fix.

**TL;DR**

In `Child.jsx` change this:

```js
  [message, setMessage] = useState('');
```

to this:

```js
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
```

**The longer answer**

When declaring variables *without* `let`, `const`, or `var` (in a non-strict environment) Javascript will create an implicit global variable. What this means is that your `message` and `setMessage` variables point to the last value they were assigned. I.e. The global variable `message` will be assigned to the result of the `useState` call in the last `Child` component that you render, which in your case is `Child 3`.

So, when you modify `message`, `Child 3` detects that change and runs the effect for `Child 3`, not the `Child` component where the change was actually made.

You can see this in action by changing the `Child` component to this and examining the output in the console:

```js
  [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data); // Will always log "child 3"
    console.log(message);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <h1>This is {data}</h1>
      <input
        onChange={(e) => {
          console.log(data); // Will log "child n" where n is the child you expect
          setMessage(e.target.value);
        }}
      ></input>
    </>
  );
```

You might also be curious as to why, if all of your `Child` components are referencing the same `message` variable, you're still able to change the inputs individually. This is because you're `input` elements are [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) and their state is being managed by the browser natively.

You can see this in action by adding the following to the `input` element in your `Child` component:

```js
  <input value={message} onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}></input>
```

**What to do in the future**

You should always, always, *always* declare your variables with `let` or `const` as it will save you headaches like this in the future. In fact, many modern transpilers such as Babel will throw an error if you don't.

When using uncontrolled inputs you should consider asking yourself why you need to do so. More often than not, a controlled input is what you actually want and in the cases where it's not, consider leaving a comment as to why it's not.

Comment: thanks , ! may i ask what is uncontrolled inputs ?

Comment: when you say : What this means is that your message and setMessage variables point to the last place they were referenced... I dont quite understand what it means... could you further explain this and uncontrolled inputs?

Comment: In short, an uncontrolled input (from the POV of React) is any `input` element where you don't pass `value` and `onChange` props. This article goes into much more detail as well: https://goshacmd.com/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/

Comment: thanks ! could you also explain the other part?  pls

Comment: I updated the answer to (I hope) better clarify, let me know if it's still not making sense and I can add a working example with code or something.

Comment: One more question, originally, I thought it is a problem of not adding key attribute into child components ... because I saw this "Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity:" in a React official doc. I dont quite understand what this means....is it also relate to me case in some sense? could you explain it to me? many thanks....

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `const` in many places:

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
```

Without the `const` keyword `message` and `setMessage` (and other stuff) leak to the window global object.

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-tree-qyr3xd?file=/src/App.js)